# how to pad y-axis for highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

by default without touching the axis, highcharts try to use as much space as possible,  what if I want to leave about half an inch on top or bottom because I want to put a logo there.  How can I set option so that there is padding on the yaxis basically?

```
-------------1

-------------2







-------------3

-------------4
```

ie chart goes from 1 to 4 but series should be plotted within 2 to 3 only.

Comment: Do you mean inside the plot area?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the minPadding and maxPadding options:

```
yAxis: {
        maxPadding: 0.2,
        minPadding:0.2
},
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.maxPadding

Answer (score 0):

You can also define [spacing](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.spacing) to add more space above axis.